# AutoForge Drawing object not displying

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have integrated AutoForge API in web application using demo account. All APIs works as expected,  but after some time duration stored drawing objects  are not displayed in bucket.

Please share the reason for such behavior & what is the solution ?

Following are the APIs we have Used:

1. Generate Token
   api/forge/oauth/token
2. List of bucket
   api/forge/oss/buckets
3. Create bucket
   api/forge/oss/buckets
4. Receive a file from the client and upload to the bucket
   api/forge/oss/objects
5. Delete bucket
   api/forge/oss/buckets/delete
6. Delete objects
   api/forge/oss/objects/delete
7. Export Data
   api/oauth/export/{urn}/{guid}/{objectid}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is different bucket's data [Retention Policies](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/).

When creating a bucket you must specify the data retention policy. In some tutorials the default policy is `transient` which means all models inside the bucket are deleted after 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks Alex got the answer at the creation bucket need to set Persistent   PostBucketsPayload bucketPayload = new PostBucketsPayload(string.Format("{0}-{1}", ClientId, bucket.bucketKey.ToLower()), null,
              PostBucketsPayload.PolicyKeyEnum.Persistent);
            return await buckets.CreateBucketAsync(bucketPayload, "US");

Comment: The persistence is not related to data objects but to buckets. AFAIK you can't change the retention policy of a bucket. You need to create a new one with the policy you want. If you're using .Net Framework, you can follow this [Upload file to OSS](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/oss/net). In `OSSController.cs`, in the `CreateBucket` method, you can change `PostBucketsPayload.PolicyKeyEnum.Transient` to a different value of the enum according to the policy you want to use.